# send you or send it to you?

Tags: prepositions

Please, which phrase is correct:

I have already finished the new recording;

1. I will send you right now.
2. I will send it to you right now.

Comment: They're both correct, but they say very different things.  In the first "you" is being send some place.  In the second, "you" is the recipient of something.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Definitely the second one!

In the first one there's no sign of what you are about to send.

Answer (score 1):

The second one, "I will send it to you right now", is grammatically correct. The first one, "I will send you right now", would be correct if you had something (a noun) to send: "I will send you *the recording* right now."

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Then in the second phrase I should say: I will send you the recording right now. Is not it?

Comment: Yes. By the way, one says "isn't it", with the contraction. :)

Comment: @shardulc Or instead of the contraction, you could say "Is it not?"

Comment: @A.Ellett yes, I had overlooked that.